# Change the SAAS variable dynamically as per database value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, saas, scss-mixins

I would like to change the background of the website and other colors too. There is a module called "Settings" on my website. Basically, I am saving the colors from that module. I am using the Laravel mix to compile the scss files.

```
SAAS files
1) _variable.scss (All variables define here like $primary-color, $secondary-color etc.)
2) _common.scss
3) app.scss
```

I would like to dynamic the `$primary-color & $secondary-color`.

I have already tried many composer packages to do these things but not getting any success.
I have tried this : https://leafo.net/scssphp/

Answer (score 2):

What about CSS Variables? Most modern browsers support it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables.

All you need is inject style in main template with custom variables from Settings module.

First, pass settings to blade view:

```php
$settings = Settings::getForCurrentUser(); // or something like that.
return view('layout.base', compact('settings'));
```

In `layout.base` add styles, and pass variables in:

```php
<style>
root {
  --primary-color: {{ $settings['primaryColor'] }};
  --secondary-color: {{ $settings['secondaryColor'] }};
  --header-color: {{ $settings['headerColor'] }};
  /* etc. */
}
</style>
```

To access css variables you need to call `var()` function. Change scss variables from `$primary-color` to:

**app.scss:**

```
button {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
button.secondary {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

Cons of this solution is that you can't use scss built-in functions like `lighten(var(--primary-color), 15%)`, because they aren't exists for scss compiler - you can use it only at client side.

Answer (score 0):

It's often easier to inject styles/CSS stored in your database into your app using JavaScript.

If that isn't an option, you should be able to store your CSS in the database as a block of CSS code, and then output the CSS within a style tag in the head of your document.

Compiling the database stored styles into your SASS is an option, yet would require an adapter to allow your compilation script/webpack access to your database.

Comment: It's mainly SAAS based project so I have to use Laravel mix to compile the SAAS & variable mixins. Thanks :)